# Control order of database logon trigger execution in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

We have two "`AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE`" triggers, each owned by different DBA-owned schemas and serving different purposes. Trigger `A` is consistently getting executed prior to trigger `B`. We need to reverse that and ensure that trigger `B` fires first.

According to the documentation, we supposedly could use "`PRECEDES ...`" syntax to control this, but when used with a database trigger it throws `ORA-25025: cannot specify PRECEDES clause`, so that's a dead-end.

Any ideas how to control which of these `AFTER LOGON` triggers fires first?

Does anybody know if `dbms_ddl.set_trigger_firing_property` can do this with some secret property value?

Comment: Why don't you use one trigger that executes several functions/procedures (to encapsulate your business logic in each) and there control execution order in a simpler manner. Check https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54199/call-multiple-functions-from-trigger

Comment: Consider also that triggers on the same event fire in alphabetical order.

Comment: We can't, they are separate products, we don't want them mixed.

Comment: Alphabetically order of schema name, trigger name, or both strung together?

Comment: Could you switch trigger codes? Put everything that's currently in trigger A into trigger B, and vice versa.

Comment: No, they are totally different products managed by different people. I know I can get the order right by consolidating their work into a single trigger or having trigger A call the procedure that trigger B calls, but that would put a dependency between the two products and we don't want that dependency.

Comment: @PepeNO, I'm afraid that it's not true that it executes in alphabetical order. I just set up a test with triggers named TRC, TRZ, TRA, TRB created in that order. They executed in the same order in which I created them, or in other words, probably in object_id order rather than in name order.

Comment: You're right, maybe it was the case in other versions, tested in ver. 21c

Answer (score 2):

PRECEDES is about editioning triggers.  Check out FOLLOWS

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  trigger trg1
  3  after logon on scott.schema
  4  begin
  5      null;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  trigger trg2
  3  after logon on scott.schema
  4  follows trg1
  5  begin
  6      null;
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

or at database level

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  trigger trg1
  3  after logon on database
  4  begin
  5      null;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  trigger trg2
  3  after logon on database
  4  follows trg1
  5  begin
  6      null;
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Comment: Interesting, I assumed PRECEDES and FOLLOWS operated the same way. I'll have to give this a try, though it does present a difficulty in that it requires one trigger to reference another trigger, creating a hard dependency. If we drop one, that could cause the other to become invalid. These triggers belong to entirely different admin tools and are managed to by two different DBAs... so hard dependencies are not desirable, but I'll definitely look into this further.

Comment: I just tested this and it doesn't work. First, it is a hard dependency requiring the trigger referenced in the FOLLOWS clause to pre-exist. That will force you to create the triggers in a particular order, which will by itself cause the execution to follow the order of creation, but it's not because of the FOLLOWS clause. This can be tested by creating your chain of triggers with FORCE to bypass the dependency error on initial creation, then replace them (create or replace) without force now that all the triggers exist. I then tested it - they fired in the order of creation, & ignored FOLLOWS